# delete parts of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

*I changed my question to make my problem more visible:*

Hello,
i could not figure out how to delete parts of a matrix in R:

For example

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3)
```

Now I would like to delete the submatrix `x[2,1:2]`, so that the final matrix is (comparable to "delete cells and move upwards" in excel) something like

```
1  4  7
3  6  8
NA NA 9.
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4):

First move the cells you want to keep up to the second row.

```
x[2,1:2] <- x[3,1:2]
```

Then set the ones you want to be missing to `NA`.

```
x[3,1:2] <- NA
```

Or, in one step,

```
x[2:3, 1:2] <- x[c(3,NA), 1:2]
```

Result, either way:

```
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    3    6    8
[3,]   NA   NA    9
```

A rudimentary function to do this could look like

```
excelremoveup <- function(mat, rows, cols) {
  keep <- which(!(1:nrow(mat)) %in% rows)
  keep <- c(keep, rep(NA, nrow(mat)-length(keep)))
  mat[, cols] <- mat[keep, cols]
  mat
}
```

You'd call it like this.

```
excelremoveup(x,2,1:2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Matrices are indexed from top to bottom, left to right. And you can set whichever submatrix you want, to NA:

```
> x[1:2,1:2] <- NA
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA    7
[2,]   NA   NA    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `data.entry()` for an excell-like way of editing a matrix:

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3)
data.entry(x)
```

simply double click the numbers you want to delete and delete them. However, I wouldn't ever recommend this over indexing because a. It requires manual input and b. You don't learn to use R in this way.

I asume you are new to R? You might want to read through one of the manuals. This is one I liked when I started:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf